Strapi connection error when making request from nextjs app
I am trying to make a request to my strapi api from my nextjs app.
For this I have the following:
This is my strapi service:
import { URLSearchParams } from "url"; 
const API_URL = "http://localhost:1337/api";


//Generic get method
export const strapiGet = async <T>(endpoint: string, params?: URLSearchParams): Promise<T> => {
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}${endpoint}${params ? `?${params}` : ''}`, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.CMS_STRAPI_TOKEN}`
        }
    });

    if(!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to retrieve in strapi: ' + endpoint);
    }

    return res.json();
}

I´ve console logged my token and it is correct.
And this is my faqs.service.st
import { StrapiResultType } from "@/types/strapi.types";
import { FAQPageType } from "@/types/faq.types";
import { strapiGet } from "../common/strapi.service";

class FAQsAPI {
    getFAQPages = async (): Promise<StrapiResultType<FAQPageType>> => strapiGet(`/faq-pages`);   
}

const faqsApi = new FAQsAPI();
export default faqsApi;

And my faq/page.tsx
import FAQSection from "@/components/faq/FAQSection";
import faqsApi from "@/services/faqs/faqs.service";

export default async function FAQPage() {
    const faqPages = await faqsApi.getFAQPages();
  return ( <main>
        <FAQSection sections={faqPages.data}/>
    </main>
  );
}

The thing is I´ve tried sending a request from insomnia and postman to strapi directly and it worked, so my strapi is running.
But there is something with my request to strapi from nextjs that is generating this issue, but I don´t know how to debug it.
In the network tab from my devtools I get a status 500 in the request.
The error I get is the following in my browser:
Error: fetch failed
Source

src\services\common\strapi.service.ts (7:16) @ async strapiGet

   5 | //Generic get method
   6 | export const strapiGet = async <T>(endpoint: string, params?: URLSearchParams): Promise<T> => {
>  7 | const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}${endpoint}${params ? `?${params}` : ''}`, {
     |            ^
   8 |     headers: {
   9 |         'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.CMS_STRAPI_TOKEN}`
  10 |     }

Call Stack
async FAQPage
src\app\faq\page.tsx (5:21)

And in my console I am having a connection error:
 ⨯ TypeError: fetch failed
    at async strapiGet (./src/services/common/strapi.service.ts:8:17)
    at async FAQPage (./src/app/faq/page.tsx:13:22)
Cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:1337
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 1337
}
 ⨯ TypeError: fetch failed
    at async strapiGet (./src/services/common/strapi.service.ts:8:17)
    at async FAQPage (./src/app/faq/page.tsx:13:22)

My url is correct and the token too.
The request my nextjs app is trying to make is http://localhost:3000/faq where this makes a request to my strapi api.

try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost e.g. http://127.0.0.1:1337/api i think it's issue with windows firewall and node

@antokhio Thanks! It worked by using the local ip address.

first time this has happened to me, after disabling the windows firewall it seems to be working fine. thanks to @antokhio his answer is also effective.
another way to solve it permanently
